# R-Loop through data frame and count values greater than a value and removing rows

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I want to loop through a large dataframe counting in the first column how many values >0, removing those rows that were counted.... then moving on to column 2 counting the number of values>0 and removing those rows etc...

the data frame

```
  taxonomy A B C
1      cat 0 2 0
2      dog 5 1 0
3    horse 3 0 0
4    mouse 0 0 4
5     frog 0 2 4
6     lion 0 0 2
```

can be generated with

```
DF1 = structure(list(taxonomy = c("cat", "dog","horse","mouse","frog", "lion"),
                A = c(0L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L), C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 2L)), 
                .Names = c("taxonomy", "A", "B", "C"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and i expect the outcome to be

```
      A B C
count 2 2 2
```

i wrote this loop but it does not remove the rows as it goes

```
res <- data.frame(DF1[1,], row.names = c('count'))
for(n in 1:ncol(DF1)) {
  res[colnames(DF1)[n]] <- sum(DF1[n])
  DF1[!DF1[n]==1] 
  }
```

it gives this incorrect result

```
      A B C
count 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can update the dataset in each run.  Create a temporary dataset without the 'taxonomy' column ('tmp').  Initiate a `named` `vector` ('n'), loop through the columns of 'tmp', get a logical index based on whether the column is greater than 0 ('i1'), get the `sum` of TRUE values, update the 'n' for the corresponding column, then update the 'tmp' by removing those rows using 'i1' as row index

```
tmp <- DF1[-1]
n <- setNames(numeric(ncol(tmp)), names(tmp))
for(i in seq_len(ncol(tmp))) {
           i1 <- tmp[[i]] > 0
           n[i] <- sum(i1)
           tmp <- tmp[!i1, ]}
n
#  A B C 
#  2 2 2
```

---

It can also be done with `Reduce`

```
sapply(Reduce(function(x, y) y[!x] > 0, DF1[3:4],
         init = DF1[,2] > 0, accumulate = TRUE ), sum)
#[1] 2 2 2
```

---

Or using `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
accumulate(DF1[3:4], ~ .y[!.x] > 0, .init = DF1[[2]] > 0) %>% 
                 map_int(sum)
#[1] 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do ...

```
DF = DF1[, -1]
cond = DF != 0
p = max.col(cond, ties="first")
fp = factor(p, levels = seq_along(DF), labels = names(DF))
table(fp)

# A B C 
# 2 2 2
```

To account for rows that are all zeros, I think this works:

```
fp[rowSums(cond) == 0] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with `Reduce` and `sapply`:

```
> first <- Reduce(function(a,b) b[a==0], df[-1], accumulate=TRUE)
> first
[[1]]
[1] 0 5 3 0 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 2 0 2 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 4 2

> then <- sapply(setNames(first, names(df[-1])), function(x) length(x[x>0]))
> then
A B C 
2 2 2
```

Comment: I now noticed that the same approach is used in the second part of akrun's answer. However, there are some differences in implementation, so I'm not deleting my answer (actually, undeleted it).